# Suppose two integers $a,N$, where N is prime, is there a difference between requiring $gcd(a,N)=1$ and $N \not\mid \!\!\;a $?

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

This is probably painfully obvious but I wanted to confirm if there's any difference between requiring that the $gcd(a,N)=1$ or $N \not\mid \!\!\;a $ if N is prime? That is, could you use either requirement and achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: only difference is the time you need to type this in $\LaTeX$ ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, each requirement implies the other. If $\gcd(a,N)=1$ then obviously $N$ can't divide $a$ because otherwise $N$ would be a common divisor of $a,N$ which is bigger than $1$.

Now suppose $N$ does not divide $a$. Let $d$ be a positive common divisor of $a,N$. Since $N$ is prime we know $d=N$ or $d=1$. But $N$ does not divide $a$, hence $d=1$. So $1$ is the only positive common divisor of $a,N$, hence it is the $\gcd$.

Comment: Again forgive naiveté: "Since  is prime we know = or =1." Why do we know that = or =1 if  is prime? Why couldn't = or =1 so 1 is the only positive common divisor of ,, hence it is the gcd?

Comment: What is a prime number? $N$ is prime if its positive divisors are $1$ and $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Negate: $ $ prime $\, \color{#c00}{p\mid a} \iff p\mid a,p\iff \overbrace{p\mid (a,p)\iff \color{#c00}{(a,p)\neq 1}}^{\textstyle \hphantom{p\mid (a,p)} \ {\Longleftarrow\ \   (a,p)\mid p}}$